# Перевод терминов

Tags: иноязычная-лексика

здравствуйте,если в арабском языке указательное местоимение называется именем указательным,как лучше называть при переводе,во время обучения арабскому, а также при составлении книги?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы пишете о грамматике арабского языка, то и термины должны быть из этого же языка. Так и писать ИМЯ УКАЗАТЕЛЬНОЕ, а рядом можно пояснение(в русск.яз.- указат. мест.)

Comment: спасибо,в арабском языке есть имя множественного числа, и арабисты переводят его как имя собирательное  , может перевести его именем множественного числа?... к тому же некоторые из этих имен являются существительными собирательными в русском языке ,а некоторые нет...

Comment: Если Вы уверены, что правильный термин ИМЯ МНОЖ,ЧИСЛА. так и надо писать, а почему арабисты переводят как имя собирательное?Может, по аналогии с другим языком? Морфология в разных языках различается.Эти вопросы нужно задавать не здесь, а на профессиональных сайтах переводчиков. Там много разных нюансов. Я в переводческом деле не спец.

Comment: я все перечитал все, все арабисты подгоняют под русский язык, имена называют местоимениями...например в арабском языке в глагольном предложении нет подлежащего и сказуемого ,а главные члены глагол(при разборе глагол это и часть речи и член предложения)и действующее лицо,которое должно стоять только после глагола,все арабисты в переводе переводят подлежащее и сказуемое, они как будто друг у друга переписывали,а спрашивать сейчас не у кого все ,просто,переписывают из книг ,которые написали арабисты.А когда преподаешь все не сходится,хочу написать так ,чтобы всем было понятно...

Comment: Тогда нужно писать так, как есть в арабском языке ,но с параллельными пояснениями в скобках, как обстоит дело в русском языке.

Comment: большое спасибо!!!

Comment: Рада, если чем-то помогла.

Comment: Двойственность - наличие двух взглядов на что-либо.В лингвистике, например,прямой видимый текст как знаковая система и контекст(восприятие), в математике своё, ...Двойственное число - категория числа для обозначения двух или парных предметов

Comment: спасибо,теперь я понял причину,в русском языке множественное число взято от слова много,а в арабском языке от слова собирать( جَمْعٌ мн. جُمُوعٌ 1) собирание, объединение; كلمتهم ~ или شملهم ~ образн. объединение, сплочение; 2) сбор; 3) мат. сложение; 4) собрание; 5) сборище, толпа; 6) грам. множественное число), а не от слова много, и поэтому когда арабисты перевели имя собирательное, у них сошлось,а множественное число они не стали переводить буквально ,потому что получилось бы что то вроде собирательного числа(или добавляющегося,прибавляющегося)  вместо множественного числа.

Comment: поэтому и получилось вместо имени собирательного имя множественного числа

Answer (score 0):

Термин на арабском приведите. 
А то уже смешно становится.

Comment: اسم الجنس الجمعي اسم الجنس الآحادي اسم الجمع جمع الجمع اسم الجنس الإفرادي здесь пять терминов ,переведите ,только точно , чтобы и с русской и с арабской грамматикой сходилось,не советую  пользоваться переводчиком ,никогда не переведет ,а в книгах можете не искать, то с одной то с другой грамматикой сходится , и еще у арабов два вида имен(существительных) собирательных ,во втором виде к единственному числу добавляется буква ة или ي ... или как минимум переведите как сможете,в помощь предлагаю обратиться.либо к сильнейшему арабисту,которого знаете либо к арабу филологу.

Comment: известные арабисты Шарбатов, Ибрагимов,Чернов,Крачковский,Баранов,Маммадов и Кузьмин, в их книгах не ищите, там только термины для начинающих, для тех кто лет пять занимался,а если  арабский знаете, заходите сюда на самый сильный сайт грамматики арабского языка, регистрируйтесь, спрашивайте. http://www.alfaseeh.com/vb/forum.php ... спасибо!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста. 
Вы вообще-то про один термин говорили. 
Арабского я не знаю, но один термин был нашел способ перевести.
А если вы знаете арабский, так зачем спрашиваете?

Comment: Вы ,просто, не поняли мой первый вопрос или я его неправильно задал,но на мои вопросы уже ответила Людмила. Спасибо всем!!!